# Cats: Map with a function which results in F[_]

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I have a function:

```
def mapIt(id: Int): F[String]
```

What is the best way to map a collection using it, if the result is used in constructor of a case class? I currently do something like this:

```
List(1, 2, 3, 4).map( id => mapIt(id).map(SomeCaseClass(id, _))).toList.sequence
```

Comment: Do you have any context bounds on `F`?

Comment: yes, it's a Monad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map some `Monad[Int]` into `Monad[SomeCaseClass]` just using `map` function (if `F` is `Monad` then it can be converted to `List` using `ListInstances.catsStdInstancesForList` from `cats.instances.list`). After that all you need is just `flatMap` your list of `Int` into list of `SomeCaseClass`:

```scala
import cats.Monad
import cats.instances.list._
import scala.language.higherKinds

case class SomeCaseClass(id: Int, name: String)

def mapIt[F[_]: Monad](id: Int): F[String] = Monad[F].pure((id + 10).toString)

List(1, 2, 3, 4).flatMap(id => mapIt(id).map(x => SomeCaseClass(id, x)))
//List(
//  SomeCaseClass(1,11), 
//  SomeCaseClass(2,12), 
//  SomeCaseClass(3,13), 
//  SomeCaseClass(4,14)
//)
```

### More detailed explanation

in function `mapIt`:

```scala
def mapIt[F[_]: Monad](id: Int): F[String]
```

compiler expect some `F[_]` which should have some `Monad` implicit.
When you call `mapIt` inside `flatMap` function, compiler looking for some `Monad` over the `Int`:

```scala
List(1, 2, 3, 4).flatMap{
  id => mapIt(id) // looking for Monad[Int]
}
```

and found it in the imported instances:
`import cats.instances.list._`

From `ListInstances`:

```scala
implicit val catsStdInstancesForList: Traverse[List] with Alternative[List] with Monad[List] with CoflatMap[List] =
    new Traverse[List] with Alternative[List] with Monad[List] with CoflatMap[List] { ... }
```

after it's just working with common `Monad` and map `Int` into `SomeCaseClass`. In the end it's just flatten `List` of `SomeCaseClass`es into.